# replace ipset with bash script

Tags: bash, iptables

So what I'm trying to do is to get "bad" ip's from this page

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stamparm/ipsum/master/ipsum.txt

Then I made a script that replaces ipsets to block, by replacing old ipset with one that holds the ip numbers from above mentioned place.

Was long time ago I wrote it. Now I came back to it. And I'm not really shure it works. Because when I run `ipset list > temporaryfile`
then I dont think all numbers in temporaryfile are found in newblacklist.txt
Here is the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Variable holding the path to the textfile used in this script
textfile='/home/userName/Blacklist/newblacklist.txt'

# create and add blacklist if not created and add to iptables
created=$(ipset list -name | grep -c blacklist)
if [[ $created == 0 ]]; then
    echo creating blacklist
    ipset create blacklist hash:net
    iptables -I INPUT -m set --match-set blacklist src -j DROP 
else
    echo blacklist already there
fi


# create and add tempblacklist if not created and add to iptables
created=$(ipset list -name | grep -c tempblacklist)
if [[ $created == 0 ]]; then
    echo creating tempblacklist
    ipset create tempblacklist hash:net
    iptables -I INPUT -m set --match-set tempblacklist src -j DROP 
else
    echo tempblacklist already there
    ipset flush tempblacklist
fi

# create a new blacklis.txt file if not there
# If there, clear it by means of rm and touch
if [ ! -e $textfile ]; then
    echo creating new blacklist.txt file
    touch $textfile
else
    echo Emptying existing blacklist.txt file
    rm $textfile;
    touch $textfile;
fi

# Get the bad ip list from site and save in newblacklist.txt file
curl --compressed https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stamparm/ipsum/master/ipsum.txt 2>/dev/null>$textfile

#check if there is a list with new bad ips
#$created shows 0 if there is no such list
created=$(ipset list -name | grep -c newblacklist) 

# Uses $created to check if there is a newblacklist list in ipset
# If there is no list creates one, otherwise flushes the existing one
if [[ $created == 0 ]]; then
    echo Creating new newblacklist list in ipset 
    ipset create newblacklist hash:net
else
    echo Flushing existing list
    ipset flush newblacklist
fi

# Clean input from comments and other stuff
variable=$(grep -v "#" $textfile | grep -v -E "\s[1-2]$" | cut -f 1)
for ip in $variable;
do
    ipset add newblacklist $ip
done


ipset swap blacklist tempblacklist

ipset flush blacklist

ipset swap newblacklist blacklist

ipset flush tempblacklist
```

The newblacklist.txt does seem to look identical to the content in the repo mentioned above.
Basically Im not confident the iptable gets updated to ban whats currently in the repo, when I run the script.